# Regular expression to replace several html attributes

Tags: html, regex

i have this html:

```
<table style="width: 128px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<colgroup span="1"><col span="2" width="64"></col></colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr height="20">
<td width="64" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="xl65" dir="rtl" width="64"><strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td class="xl67" dir="rtl" width="64" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="xl66" dir="ltr" width="64">T3500&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td class="xl68" width="64" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="xl65" dir="rtl" width="64"><strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr height="48">
<td class="xl67" dir="rtl" width="64" height="48">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="xl66" dir="ltr" width="64">Intel&reg; X58 Chipset&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr height="33">
<td class="xl70" dir="rtl" width="64" height="33">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="xl69" dir="ltr" width="64">10/100/1000&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td class="xl68" width="64" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="xl65" dir="rtl" width="64"><strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr height="96">
<td class="xl67" dir="rtl" width="64" height="96">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="xl66" dir="ltr" width="64">One Intel Xeon W3503(2.4GHz,4.8GT/s,4MB,DC)&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td class="xl68" width="64" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i want to replace all style, dir, height, width and class with nothing so it will be removed

this is what i have tried for some of them and it worked in an online tester but didn't work in notepad++

```
( class=\"([^\"]*)\"){0,} (width=\"([^\"]*)\"){0,} (height=\"([^\"]*)\"){0,}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
\s*(?:style|dir|height|width|class)\s*=\s*"[^"]*"\s*
```

Of course this will remove texts like `style="hello"` wherever they may occur, also outside of tags.

It may be that Notepad++ doesn't support the `\s` shorthand. Try using

```
[ ]*(?:style|dir|height|width|class) *= *"[^"]*" *
```

instead and see if that works. The `[ ]` at the start can be replaced by a single space.

Comment: changed it to: \s*(?:style|dir|height|width|class)\s*=\s*"[^"]*" and it works in online tester but does not work in notepad++

Comment: You *nearly* solved my problem! Unfortunately, your solution breaks when HTML is <input data-blah-style="blah" some-attribute="blah-again" />. It outputs <input data-blah-some-attribute="blah-again" />. Any chance you could fix it for my scenario? My regex kung fu is weak...

Comment: This is my attempt at a fix: \s*(?:\s+style|dir|height|width|class)\s*=\s*"[^"]*"\s*

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, at least for your example:

\s*(style|dir|height|width|class)="[^"]+"\s*