# Remove alt attributes from HTML

Tags: regex, replace

I have a huge HTML file which I'm trying to format to be able to import the content into a different application.  The one thing that remains is that I need to remove all alt attributes from the HTML entirely.  They all have different values and there are around 5000 of them, so clearly a straight find & replace isn't an option.  Perhaps there's a way to find and replace with regex in Visual Web developer?

The tools/skills I have available are: HTML, Javascript, ASP (Classic), a little bit of .NET, Visual Web Developer Express 2010, but the only similar things I can find are PHP-based and they don't explain fully enough for me to set up a solution and feed the HTML to it.

I've found things like this: [Regular expression to replace several html attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612779/regular-expression-to-replace-several-html-attributes), which give suggestions of regex functions which do similar things, but I'm not even sure how to run a regex function on a straight HTML file (my browser is struggling with the size of the HTML file as it is, so I don't think javascript is going to cut it).

Can anyone suggest the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks folks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use Visual Studio, you can try the Regex search & replace option, though the implementation of regexes in Visual Studio is pretty different from other regex engines.

Here's a short article about it:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html

As it says in the article, the builtin regex engine isn't ideal. They mention a plugin with implements standard regexes though:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9125/Standard-Regular-Expression-Searcher-Addin-For-VS

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise there was a regex replace option in the find console in Visual Web Developer Express, so that's a great start, thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a regex replace plugin for Visual Studio which uses a standard regex engine.

Comment: Thanks.  I ran this `alt="{[^\"]+}"` in the find, and replaced it with nothing, which seems to have stripped out the content of the alt attributes, so I can now do a find and replace on `alt=""` and the should be gone completely.  Need to do some thorough checking as I don't understand regex one little bit, but initial impressions are that it worked...

Comment: Enable regex filters in Visual Studio search and use `data-ng-*.*?="*.*?"` or `ng-*.*?="*.*?"` to remove all Angular attributes from a HTML.